# Reporting Services Configuration Manager User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to connect the Reporting Services Configuration Manager installed on my application server to a ReportServer database located on another server.

I am using a domain account, to connect Reporting Services Configuration Manager to the database.

the domain account has the following permissions on these databases:

- public and RSExecRole roles for the ReportServer database.
- RSExecRole role for the master, msdb, and ReportServerTempDB databases.

futhermore the domain account has db owner permissions on ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB

In the Database Server section I specify the sql server\instance and use Current User- Integrated Security. I am logged in as the domain user that I want to use to connect to the database. The username also shows this particular user which is correct. Test Connection is successful

In the Database section I select the ReportServer

In the Credentials section I tried Authentication Type both as Service Credentials and Windows Credentials but they both result in the same error below.

The error happens during Applying connection rights.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: User does not have permission to perform this action.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(SqlConnection conn, String script, ICommandWrapperFactory commandWrapper)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.SqlClientTools.SqlTools.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)
```

from error log:---

```
<Header>
  <Product>Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 2009.0100.1600.01 ((KJ_RTM).100402-1539 )</Product>
  <Locale>English (United States)</Locale>
  <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
  <Path>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\Logfiles\ReportServerService__01_16_2014_13_11_11.log</Path>
  <SystemName>CMTOWDPBHSAPP02</SystemName>
  <OSName>Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200</OSName>
  <OSVersion>6.2.9200</OSVersion>
  <ProcessID>1776</ProcessID>
  <Virtualization>Hypervisor</Virtualization>
</Header>
rshost!rshost!7b0!01/16/2014-13:11:11:: i INFO: CLR runtime is initialized.
rshost!rshost!7b0!01/16/2014-13:11:11:: i INFO: Derived memory configuration based on physical memory as 8388084 KB
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!7d4!01/16/2014-13:11:11:: i INFO: Entered managed ServiceMain in DefaultDomain.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing ConnectionType to '0'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing SecureConnectionLevel to '0'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing CleanupCycleMinutes to '10' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MaxActiveReqForOneUser to '20' requests(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing DatabaseQueryTimeout to '120' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsScavengerCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsDbCycle to '60' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RunningRequestsAge to '30' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MaxScheduleWait to '5' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing DisplayErrorLink to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing WebServiceUseFileShareStorage to 'False'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonFlags to '1064'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonDumpOnExceptions to 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing WatsonDumpExcludeIfContainsExceptions to 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException,System.Web.UI.ViewStateException,System.OutOfMemoryException,System.Web.HttpException,System.IO.IOException,System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing AuthenticationTypes to '4'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel to 'Off'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario to 'Proxy'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing EnableAuthPersistence to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing IsSchedulingService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing IsNotificationService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing IsEventService to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing PollingInterval to '10' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing WindowsServiceUseFileShareStorage to 'False'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MemorySafetyMargin to '80' percent as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MemoryThreshold to '90' percent as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing RecycleTime to '720' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MaxAppDomainUnloadTime to '30' minute(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MaxQueueThreads to '0' thread(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: w WARN: Initializing UrlRoot to default value of ''  because it was incorrectly specified in Configuration file as ''.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing IsWebServiceEnabled to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing IsReportManagerEnabled to 'True'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing MaxConnections to '2'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing Timeout to '10' second(s) as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing AppID to '(Default)'  as specified in Configuration file.
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Initializing CacheLevel to 'Default'  as specified in Configuration file.
resourceutilities!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Enterprise
configmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Using report server internal url http://localhost:80/ReportServer.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Using report server external url http://CMTOWDPBHSAPP02:80/ReportServer.
configmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Using url root http://CMTOWDPBHSAPP02:80/ReportServer.
rshost!rshost!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Configuring maxPhysicalCpu=8, minLogicalCpu=0
rshost!rshost!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Logical processor per physical processor 4
rshost!rshost!7c4!01/16/2014-13:11:13:: i INFO: Maximum logical CPU is 4
library!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:08:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:08:: e ERROR: Error initializing configuration from the database: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 WindowsService_0 started.
library!WindowsService_0!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
servicecontroller!WindowsService_0!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: e ERROR: Error initializing configuration from the database: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
resourceutilities!WindowsService_0!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Enterprise
library!WindowsService_0!4f4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!WindowsService_0!4f4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: e ERROR: ServiceStartThread: Exception caught while starting service. Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
library!WindowsService_0!4f4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: e ERROR: ServiceStartThread: Attempting to start service again...
rpcserver!DefaultDomain!4f4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: i INFO: RPC Server started.
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!4f4!01/16/2014-13:10:09:: i INFO: RPC Server started. Endpoint name ='ReportingServices$MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER'
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: The UserAccountControl value for the service account is 66048
rshost!rshost!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Registered url=http://+:80/ReportServer/, vdir=/ReportServer, pdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer.
rshost!rshost!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Currently registered url http://+:80/ReportServer/ on endpoint 2
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: The UserAccountControl value for the service account is 66048
rshost!rshost!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Registered url=http://+:80/Reports/, vdir=/Reports, pdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager.
rshost!rshost!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Currently registered url http://+:80/Reports/ on endpoint 3
rshost!rshost!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Endpoint 4 is disabled and no url is registered vdir=/ReportServer/ReportBuilder, pdir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\ReportBuilder.
resourceutilities!DefaultDomain!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Maximum memory limit is 2097152Mb
rshost!rshost!7c4!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Derived memory configuration based on physical memory as 8388084 KB
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!480!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Total Physical memory: 8589398016
rpcserver!DefaultDomain!6e8!01/16/2014-13:10:10:: i INFO: Process monitoring started.
library!DefaultDomain!9d0!01/16/2014-13:11:31:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9e0!01/16/2014-13:12:22:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9e0!01/16/2014-13:12:22:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!834!01/16/2014-13:19:53:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9d8!01/16/2014-13:19:53:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!834!01/16/2014-15:41:28:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9e0!01/16/2014-15:42:28:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!834!01/16/2014-15:42:28:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9d8!01/16/2014-15:46:10:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9d0!01/16/2014-15:46:10:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!9e0!01/16/2014-15:58:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
library!DefaultDomain!7d8!01/16/2014-15:58:42:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: No DSN present in configuration file, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException: The report server has encountered a configuration error. ;
```

Answer (score 8):

The very bottom of this link says you also need db_owner on master and MSDB

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlreportingservices.aspx?ID=21cdcb58-2348-451c-b51a-3d55167f9be2

To paraphrase the link:

> What stands out is “No DSN present in configuration file” so I created
>   a System DSN and got the same results. I then went to the
>   rsreportserver.config file and manually entered the DSN. This showed
>   up in the log:
>
> "FailedToDecryptConfigInformationException: The encrypted value for
>   the " Dsn" configuration setting cannot be decrypted"
>
> So it appears that Reporting Services has to encrypt the DSN and save
>   it in the file.
>
> I searched other sites and found people who had the “No DSN present in
>   configuration file” message because they did not create create the
>   database using the Report Server Configuration Manager. Creating the
>   database should input the DSN info in the rsreportserver.config file.
>   However, it is not doing so in this case.

Comment: Yes, I had already gone to report services config manager and created a test reporting DB just for this. I also see a encrpyted blob of text between the DSN tags of reprotserver.config file. It still does not work for me.

Comment: Also if the ReportServer database needs to be created, the user needs to be a member of dbcreator Server Role.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a case of running into [Kerberos Authentication](https://www.google.com/search?q=kerberos%20authentication) constraints. You'd have to modify the first computer's Delegation records in Active Directory to make it a trusted server. Once that happens, it should allow it to pass on the user's authentication. I don't have domain admin rights to our server so I haven't been able to try it myself, but I have bumped into this same issue a few times.

Edit: Another option may be to allow SQL Server Authentication and create a user account in SQL Server. Then you'll be able to bypass the Kerberos restraints and SQL Server can pass the login.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that the Reporting Services database is down.

Have you accidentally detatched what you thought was an old or temporary database, but it turns out to be part of the SQL Server environment?

Check that ReportSever and ReportSeverTempDB are both attached in SQL Server and running.